# What is the KDE Disk Utility's Name?

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, default-programs

I know about gnome-disks, but I'm trying to find the KDE analog package name.

Here is a picture of it. It appears as the KDE Partition Manager in the File Menu on KDE.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually KDE's partitionmanager is not analogous to gnome-disks which is a simple tool to only show the disks attached to your system. But it's analogous to [GParted](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/) which is a partition manager.

Comment: Oof, I though gnome-disks was basically gparted since they looked similar lol Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `partitionmanager` . Take a look at [this](https://kde.org/applications/system/org.kde.partitionmanager).